# how to repaint only part of a QWidget in PyQt4?

Tags: python, buffer, pyqt4, qwidget

I'm trying to create a program that displays a large grid of numbers (say, filling up a 6 by 4000 grid), where the user can move a cursor around via keyboard or mouse and enter in numbers into the grid. (This is for a guitar tablature program.) I'm new to python GUI programming, and thus far my idea is to have a very large QWidget window (say, 1000x80000 pixels) inside of a QScrollArea inside of the main window. The problem is that every mouse click or cursor movement causes the whole thing to repaint, causing a delay, when I just want to repaint whatever changes I just made to make things faster. In PyQt, is there a way to buffer already-painted graphics and change just the graphics that need changing?

edit: I've posted the code below, which I've run with python3.3 on Mac OS 10.7. The main point is that in the TabWindow **init** function, the grid size can be set by numXGrid and numYGrid (currently set to 200 and 6), and this grid is filled with random numbers by the generateRandomTablatureData() method. If the grid is filled with numbers, then there's a noticeable lag with every key press, which gets worse with larger grids. (There is also an initial delay due to generating the data, but my question is on the delay after each key press which I assume is due to having to repaint every number.)

There are two files. This is the main one, which I called FAIT.py:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
import random
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

import Tracks

# generate tracks
tracks = [Tracks.Track(), Tracks.Track(), Tracks.Track()]

fontSize = 16
# margins
xMar = 50
yMar = 50
trackMar = 50      # margin between tracks

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()        
        self.initUI()
        end_time = time.time()
        print("Initializing time was %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))

    def initUI(self): 
        # attach QScrollArea to MainWindow                      
        l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        l.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        l.setSpacing(0)
        s=QtGui.QScrollArea()
        l.addWidget(s)

        # attach TabWindow to QScrollArea so we can paint on it
        self.tabWindow=TabWindow(self)  
        self.tabWindow.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        vbox=QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.tabWindow)

        s.setWidget(self.tabWindow)

        self.positionWindow()   # set size and position of main window
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')    
        self.show()

    def positionWindow(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        width = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().width() - 100
        height = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().height() - 100
        self.resize(width, height)
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())     

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        print('key pressed in MainWindow')

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print('mouse click in MainWindow')


class TabWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # size of tablature grid
        numXGrid = 200
        numYGrid = 6

        # initialize tablature information first
        for i in range(0, len(tracks)):
            tracks[i].numXGrid = numXGrid        
        self.arrangeTracks()    # figure out offsets for each track
        self.trackFocusNum = 0       # to begin with, focus is on track 0

        self.windowSizeX = tracks[0].x0 + tracks[0].dx*(tracks[0].numXGrid+2)
        self.windowSizeY = tracks[0].y0
        for i in range(0, len(tracks)):
            self.windowSizeY = self.windowSizeY + tracks[i].dy * tracks[i].numYGrid + trackMar
        self.resize(self.windowSizeX,self.windowSizeY)    # size of actual tablature area

        # generate random tablature data for testing
        self.generateRandomTablatureData()


    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        print('key pressed in TabWindow')
        i = self.trackFocusNum
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            tracks[i].moveCursorUp()
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            tracks[i].moveCursorDown()
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
            tracks[i].moveCursorLeft()
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
            tracks[i].moveCursorRight()

        # check for number input
        numberKeys = (QtCore.Qt.Key_0,
                      QtCore.Qt.Key_1,  
                      QtCore.Qt.Key_2, 
                      QtCore.Qt.Key_3, 
                      QtCore.Qt.Key_4, 
                      QtCore.Qt.Key_5, 
                      QtCore.Qt.Key_6, 
                      QtCore.Qt.Key_7, 
                      QtCore.Qt.Key_8, 
                      QtCore.Qt.Key_9)
        if e.key() in numberKeys:
            num = int(e.key())-48
            # add data
            tracks[i].data.addToTab(tracks[i].iCursor, tracks[i].jCursor, num)

            # convert entered number to pitch and play note (do later)

        # spacebar, backspace, or delete remove data
        if e.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Space, QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace, QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete):
            tracks[i].data.removeFromTab(tracks[i].iCursor, tracks[i].jCursor)

        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print('mouse click in TabWindow')
        xPos = e.x()
        yPos = e.y()
        # check tracks one by one
        for i in range(0, len(tracks)):
            if (tracks[i].isPositionInside(xPos, yPos)):
                tracks[i].moveCursorToPosition(xPos, yPos)
                self.trackFocusNum = i
                break
            else:
                continue

        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)

        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
        qp.drawRect(0, 0, self.windowSizeX, self.windowSizeY)

        self.paintTracks(qp)
        self.paintTunings(qp)
        self.paintCursor(qp)
        self.paintNumbers(qp)
        qp.end()

    def paintTracks(self, qp):
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
        for i in range(0, len(tracks)):
            qp.drawPolyline(tracks[i].polyline)

    def paintCursor(self, qp):
        i = self.trackFocusNum
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        qp.drawPolygon(tracks[i].getCursorQPolygon())

    def paintNumbers(self, qp):
        # iterate through tracks, and iterate through numbers on each track
        for i in range(0, len(tracks)):
            # make sure track has data to draw
            if len(tracks[i].data.data) > 0:
                for j in range(0, len(tracks[i].data.data)):
                    # do actual painting here

                    # first set color to be inverse cursor color if at cursor
                    if i == self.trackFocusNum and  \
                       tracks[i].iCursor == tracks[i].data.data[j][0] and  \
                       tracks[i].jCursor == tracks[i].data.data[j][1]:
                        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.white)
                    else:
                        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
                    font = QtGui.QFont('Helvetica', fontSize)
                    qp.setFont(font) 
                    text = str(tracks[i].data.data[j][2])
                    x1 = tracks[i].convertIndexToPositionX(tracks[i].data.data[j][0])
                    y1 = tracks[i].convertIndexToPositionY(tracks[i].data.data[j][1])
                    dx = tracks[i].dx
                    dy = tracks[i].dy

                    # height and width of number character(s)
                    metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
                    tx = metrics.width(text)
                    ty = metrics.height()

                    # formula for alignment:
                    # xMar = (dx-tx)/2 plus offset
                    x11 = x1 + (dx-tx)/2
                    y11 = y1 + dy/2+ty/2
                    qp.drawText(x11, y11, text)

    def paintTunings(self, qp):
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        font = QtGui.QFont('Helvetica', fontSize)
        qp.setFont(font)        
        for i in range(0, len(tracks)):
            for j in range(0, tracks[i].numStrings):
                text = tracks[i].convertPitchToLetter(tracks[i].stringTuning[j])
                # height and width of characters
                metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
                tx = metrics.width(text)
                ty = metrics.height()

                x11 = tracks[i].x0 - tx - 10
                y11 = tracks[i].convertIndexToPositionY(j) + (tracks[i].dy+ty)/2
                qp.drawText(x11, y11, text)

    def arrangeTracks(self):
        tracks[0].x0 = xMar
        tracks[0].y0 = yMar
        tracks[0].generateGridQPolyline()

        for i in range(1, len(tracks)):
            tracks[i].x0 = xMar
            tracks[i].y0 = tracks[i-1].y0 + tracks[i-1].height + trackMar
            tracks[i].generateGridQPolyline()

    def generateRandomTablatureData(self):
        t1 = time.time()
        for i in range(0, len(tracks)):
            # worst case scenario: fill every number
            for jx in range(0, tracks[i].numXGrid):
                for jy in range(0, tracks[i].numYGrid):
                    val = random.randint(0,9)
                    tracks[i].data.addToTab(jx, jy, val)
        t2 = time.time()
        print("Random number generating time was %g seconds" % (t2 - t1))



def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the other file, Tracks.py, which contains the Track class and supplementary methods:

```
# contains classes and methods relating to individual tracks

import math
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

# class for containing information about a track
class Track:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = TabulatureData()

        # position offset
        self.x0 = 0
        self.y0 = 0

        self.dx = 20    # default rectangle width
        self.dy = 40    # default rectangle height

        # current cursor index coordinates
        self.iCursor = 0
        self.jCursor = 0

        # default size of grid 
        self.numXGrid = 4000
        self.numYGrid = 6
        self.numStrings = self.numYGrid

        # calculated maximum width and height in pixels
        self.maxWidth = self.dx * self.numXGrid
        self.maxHeight = self.dy * self.numYGrid

        # generate points of grid and cursor
        self.generateGridQPolyline()

        # tuning
        self.setTuning([40, 45, 50, 55, 59, 64])

        # calculate bounds
        self.height = self.numYGrid*self.dy
        self.width = self.numXGrid*self.dx

    def getCursorIndexX(self, xPos):
        iPos = int(math.floor( (xPos-self.x0)/self.dx ))
        return iPos

    def getCursorIndexY(self, yPos):
        jPos = int(math.floor( (yPos-self.y0)/self.dy ))
        return jPos

    def convertIndexToCoordinates(self, iPos, jPos):
        return [self.ConvertIndexToPositionX(iPos), 
                self.ConvertIndexToPositionY(jPos)]

    def convertIndexToPositionX(self, iPos):
        return self.x0 + iPos*self.dx

    def convertIndexToPositionY(self, jPos):
        return self.y0 + jPos*self.dy

    def getCursorQPolygon(self):
        x1 = self.convertIndexToPositionX(self.iCursor)
        y1 = self.convertIndexToPositionY(self.jCursor)
        x2 = self.convertIndexToPositionX(self.iCursor+1)
        y2 = self.convertIndexToPositionY(self.jCursor+1)
        return QtGui.QPolygonF([QtCore.QPoint(x1, y1), 
                                 QtCore.QPoint(x1, y2), 
                                 QtCore.QPoint(x2, y2), 
                                 QtCore.QPoint(x2, y1)])

    def generateGridQPolyline(self):
        self.points = []      
        self.polyline = QtGui.QPolygonF()
        for i in range(0, self.numXGrid):
            for j in range(0, self.numYGrid):
                x1 = self.convertIndexToPositionX(i)
                y1 = self.convertIndexToPositionY(j)
                x2 = self.convertIndexToPositionX(i+1)
                y2 = self.convertIndexToPositionY(j+1)
                self.points.append([(x1, y1), (x1, y2), (x2, y2), (x2, y1)])
                self.polyline << QtCore.QPoint(x1,y1) <<    \
                                 QtCore.QPoint(x1,y2) <<    \
                                 QtCore.QPoint(x2,y2) <<    \
                                 QtCore.QPoint(x2,y1) <<    \
                                 QtCore.QPoint(x1,y1)      
            # smoothly connect different rows
            jLast = self.numYGrid-1
            x1 = self.convertIndexToPositionX(i)
            y1 = self.convertIndexToPositionY(jLast)
            x2 = self.convertIndexToPositionX(i+1)
            y2 = self.convertIndexToPositionY(jLast+1)
            self.polyline << QtCore.QPoint(x2,y1)


    def isPositionInside(self, xPos, yPos):
        if (xPos >= self.x0 and xPos <= self.x0 + self.width and
            yPos >= self.y0 and yPos <= self.y0 + self.height):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def moveCursorToPosition(self, xPos, yPos):
        self.iCursor = self.getCursorIndexX(xPos)
        self.jCursor = self.getCursorIndexY(yPos)
        self.moveCursorToIndex(self.iCursor, self.jCursor)

    def moveCursorToIndex(self, iPos, jPos):
        # check if bounds are breached, and if cursor's already there, 
        # and if not, move cursor
        if iPos == self.iCursor and jPos == self.jCursor:
            return
        if iPos >= 0 and iPos < self.numXGrid:
            if jPos >= 0 and jPos < self.numYGrid:
                self.iCursor = iPos
                self.jCursor = jPos
        return

    def moveCursorUp(self):
        self.moveCursorToIndex(self.iCursor, self.jCursor-1)

    def moveCursorDown(self):
        self.moveCursorToIndex(self.iCursor, self.jCursor+1)

    def moveCursorLeft(self):
        self.moveCursorToIndex(self.iCursor-1, self.jCursor)

    def moveCursorRight(self):
        self.moveCursorToIndex(self.iCursor+1, self.jCursor)


    # return pitch in midi integer notation
    def convertNumberToPitch(self, jPos, pitchNum):
        return pitchNum + self.stringTuning[(self.numStrings-1) - jPos]   

    def convertPitchToLetter(self, pitchNum):
        p = pitchNum % 12
        letters = ('C', 'Db', 'D', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'Gb', 'G', 'Ab', 'A', 'Bb', 'B')
        return letters[p]

    def setTuning(self, tuning):
        self.stringTuning = tuning


class TabulatureData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def addToTab(self, i, j, value):
        # check if data is already there, and remove it first
        if self.getValue(i, j) > -1:
            self.removeFromTab(i, j)
        self.data.append([i, j, value])

    def getValue(self, i, j):
        possibleTuples = [x for x in self.data if x[0] == i and x[1] == j]
        if possibleTuples == []:
            return -1
        elif len(possibleTuples) > 1:
            print('Warning: more than one number at a location!')
        return possibleTuples[0][2]        # return third number of tuple

    def removeFromTab(self, i, j):
        # first get value, if it exists
        value = self.getValue(i,j)
        if value == -1:
            return
        else:        
            # if it exists, then remove
            self.data.remove([i, j, value])
```

Comment: A "large grid of numbers" sounds like a [QTableWidget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for something more general and flexible than a table widget.

Comment: In precisely what way is a tablewidget/tableview unsuitable? Given that you say you're new to python GUI programming, your question currently looks like it could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: First, I'm more interested in knowing how to solve these types of graphics problems in general than in solving this specific problem. Second, I also want to draw lines in the tablature, and to try experiments with how the numbers are presented (animating them, for example) that would be hard if I was stuck with an object intended for spreadsheet-style apps.

Comment: On your first point: if that's the case, then you're definitely in the wrong place. SO is all about _specific programming problems_. More to the point, your question needs to include actual code that reproduces the problem(s) that you're facing.

Comment: Now that I can more clearly see what you're trying to do, I have to say that my suspicions regarding the XY problem have been more or less confirmed. Qt has a [Graphics View Framework](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html) which already solves all the problems that you currently have (and more).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried QGraphicsView for a little bit, but it wasn't clear that I could do things like changing the color of text underneath a rectangle (i.e., for a cursor), and I got frustrated and switched back to the plain QPainter way. I will look into QGraphicsView further.

Comment: So I've now managed to implement QGraphicsView, and made a number of other little changes (e.g., using set methods rather than setting a child variable directly seemed to help), and the program is much faster than before.

Answer (score 1):

1000*80000 is really huge.
So,maybe you should try QGLWidget or something like that?
Or according to Qt document, you should set which region you want to repaint.

some slow widgets need to optimize by painting only the requested region: QPaintEvent::region(). This speed optimization does not change the result, as painting is clipped to that region during event processing. QListView and QTableView do this, for example.